# Correct syntax to only output custom attribute if it exists else display default one

Tags: attributes

This works perfectly, displaying a dropdown of products to offer as a free gift, the label for each option takes the name of the product.

```
<select id="select_28" class="product-custom-option" title="" name="freeGiftId">
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('-- Please Select --')?></option>
    <?php foreach($freeGifts as $giftId): ?>
    <?php $productGift = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($giftId); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $productGift->getId()?>">
        <?php echo $productGift->getName()?> /*THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION */
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I've created a custom attribute however that will be outputted instead of the name but only if it exists.

I'll use `<?php echo $productGift->getXyz(); ?>` instead of `<?php echo $productGift->getName()?>`. But I need to add an `if` statement so that it is only shown if it exists.

I'm trying this and many other variations:-

```
<select id="select_28" class="product-custom-option" title="" name="freeGiftId">
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('-- Please Select --')?></option>
    <?php foreach($freeGifts as $giftId): ?>
    <?php $productGift = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($giftId); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $productGift->getId()?>">
        <?php if ($productGift->getXyz()): ?> /*THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION */
            <?php echo $productGift->getXyz(); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $productGift->getName()?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

This isn't working though. Please could someone advise on the correct syntax to use in order to show custom attribute 'Xyz' if it exists, otherwise show the product 'name'?

Comment: What do you mean by "this isn't working"? What is the result of that?

Comment: It breaks the page (only loads up to that point in the code and then everything else after that doesn't load). Not that I can identify an error in the log for this. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to close the `if` statement. `<?php endif;?>` before `</option>`

Comment: Yes, that was it. I completely didn't even notice. :/ Thanks very much Marius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `hasXyz` to determine if the object has a value for that attribute, however assuming the value is truthy, what you have should work (it would fail if you expect it to be 0 or '').

EDIT: I can't remember for sure, but I think the closing endif is required in alternate syntax.

```
  <?php if ($productGift->getXyz()): ?> /*THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION */
      <?php echo $productGift->getXyz(); ?>
  <?php else: ?>
      <?php echo $productGift->getName()?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Oh for goodness sake, the endif escaped. I think this is it. Just testing it now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much for spotting this, the runaway endif I didn't even notice. Cheers.

Comment: Lost count of the amount of hours I've wasted chasing down such issues. I didn't even notice until after I'd replied :).